# How to set a default value in class when an object is created

Tags: java

I want to make **card number** of the **customer** is always set to **-1** when a **new customer** is created.

[Image of how code looks likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vBqM.png)

```
public Customer(int cardNumber, int yearOfBirth) {
    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
}

public int getCardNumber() {
    return cardNumber;
}

public void setCardNumber(int cardNumber) {
    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
}
```

Comment: Well, this code here looks like it does not cause the problem you're describing.

Comment: Please do not insert source code in form of an image, but insert it as text. Also, please add an example how you create an object of your `Customer` class.

Comment: @MCEmperor sorry that's what I want to make the code do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it.  Add an initializer to the field declaration.

```
public class Customer {
    private int cardNumber = -1;
    private int yearOfBirth;
    
    public Customer(int yearOfBirth) {
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    }
    
    public int getCardNumber() {
        return cardNumber;
    }
    
    public void setCardNumber(int cardNumber) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    }
}
```

Another alternative would be to explicitly initialize the field to its default value in the constructor; e.g.

```
    public Customer(int yearOfBirth) {
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.cardNumber = -1;
    }
```